# Ruby Error - Expected Array or String, Got Hash

Tags: ruby, string, google-sheets, google-api, typeerror

*EDIT* - I've re-added the commented out sections to include the other methods I've attempted to solve this to hopefully provide more insight into my process. As of now this program is working, but it sends my local spreadsheet as an attachment in place of the "temp" file that I need generated from google sheets and attached instead. This is obviously the part that I am having issues with and I need to know how to append my code accordingly to download and attach the temp file with the processed data...

Hello and thank you in advance for your help. I'm running into an issue with my Ruby program when trying to download and attach a sheets file to an email. The program is supposed to add units to reorder from a local spreadsheet and add it to the sheets file, which should then be downloaded and emailed as an attachment. I can get the program to send an email with the corresponding SKUs and QTY in the body of the email as text, and I can get the program to add the SKUs and QTY to a specified google sheet, but I cannot then download the sheet file and email it as an attachment. The exact error I'm getting is the following:

```
C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/signet-0.18.0/lib/signet/oauth_2/client.rb:420:in `scope=': Expected Array or String, got Hash (TypeError)

          raise TypeError, "Expected Array or String, got #{new_scope.class}"
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/signet-0.18.0/lib/signet/oauth_2/client.rb:193:in `update!'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/signet-0.18.0/lib/signet/oauth_2/client.rb:115:in `initialize'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/googleauth-0.17.1/lib/googleauth/service_account.rb:105:in `initialize'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/googleauth-0.17.1/lib/googleauth/service_account.rb:80:in `new'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/googleauth-0.17.1/lib/googleauth/service_account.rb:80:in `make_creds'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/google_drive-3.0.7/lib/google_drive/session.rb:89:in `from_service_account_key'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/google_drive-3.0.7/lib/google_drive/session.rb:86:in `block in from_service_account_key'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/google_drive-3.0.7/lib/google_drive/session.rb:85:in `open'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/google_drive-3.0.7/lib/google_drive/session.rb:85:in `from_service_account_key'
        from ex5.rb:38:in `insert_data'
        from ex5.rb:83:in `process_order'
        from ex5.rb:144:in `<main>'
```

Can someone please review my code and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
require 'bundler'
require 'google_drive'
require 'roo'
require 'google/apis/sheets_v4'
require 'googleauth'
require 'googleauth/stores/file_token_store'
require 'mail'
Bundler.require

begin
def read_spreadsheet(file_path)
  spreadsheet = Roo::Excelx.new(file_path)
  header = spreadsheet.row(2)
  data = []
  (3..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |i|
    row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
    data << row
  end
  data
end

def format_data_plain_text(data)
  formatted_data = ""

  data.each do |row|
    unless row['REORDER QTY'].to_i.zero? || row['AC SKU'].to_s.empty?
      sku = row['AC SKU'].to_s
      quantity = row['REORDER QTY'].to_s

      formatted_data += "#{sku}\t#{quantity}\n"
    end
  end
  formatted_data.to_s
end


def insert_data(file_path, formatted_data)
  session = GoogleDrive::Session.from_service_account_key("client_secret.json")

  spreadsheet_title = "Reorder Details"
  spreadsheet = session.spreadsheet_by_title(spreadsheet_title)
  worksheet = spreadsheet.worksheets.first

  first_empty_row = 1
  while !worksheet[first_empty_row, 1].empty? && first_empty_row <= worksheet.num_rows
    first_empty_row += 1
  end

if first_empty_row == 1
  worksheet[first_empty_row, 1] = "SKU"
  worksheet[first_empty_row, 2] = "QUANTITY"
  first_empty_row += 1
end

puts formatted_data.class
  data_lines = formatted_data.split("\n")
  data_lines.each_with_index do |line, index|
    columns = line.split("\t")
    worksheet[first_empty_row + index, 1] = columns[0]
    worksheet[first_empty_row + index, 2] = columns[1]
  end

  worksheet.save
end

def download_google_sheet(sheet_id)
  session = GoogleDrive::Session.from_service_account_key("client_secret.json")
  spreadsheet = session.spreadsheet_by_key(sheet_id)

  worksheet = spreadsheet.worksheets.first

  temp_file = Tempfile.new(['google_sheet', '.xlsx'], encoding: 'UTF-8')
  worksheet.export_as_file(temp_file.path)

  temp_file.path
  temp_file.close
end

def process_order(file_path)
  order_details = read_spreadsheet(file_path)
  formatted_data = format_data_plain_text(order_details)

  insert_data(file_path, formatted_data)

  puts "Data inserted into Google Sheets."

  sheet_id = 'numbersandletters'
  temp_file_path = download_google_sheet(sheet_id)

  send_email(file_path, temp_file_path)
end

def send_email(file_path, temp_file_path)
    # Configure your email settings
    options = {
      address: 'smtp.gmail.com',
      port: 587,
      user_name: 'email@email.com',
      password: 'password',
      domain: 'domain.com',
      authentication: 'plain',
      enable_starttls_auto: true
    }
    Mail.defaults do
      delivery_method :smtp, options
    end

    order_details = read_spreadsheet(file_path)
    formatted_data = format_data_plain_text(order_details)

    #temp_file_content = File.read(temp_file_path)

    #Specify the email content
    mail = Mail.new do
      from    'Email@email.com'
      to      'email@email.com'
      subject "Order Details:"
      body    "Hey Tim. Hope you're doing well! I just need to place an order for the following items:\n\nThis will be using Net Terms.\n\nPlease let me know if you need anything else from me! Have a great week!"
      add_file(file_path)
    end
    # Send the email
    mail.deliver!
end

#def send_email(file_path)
#  gmail = Gmail.connect("email@email.com", "password")
#
#  subject = "Reorder Details"
#  body = "Please find the attached Google Sheet with reorder details."
#
#  gmail.deliver do
#    to "email@email.com"
#    subject subject
#    text_part do
#      body body
#    end
#    add_file file_path
#  end

#  gmail.logout
#end

file_path = 'path\to\file'
process_order(file_path)



#def export_google_sheet(file_id, export_format, export_directory)
#  session = GoogleDrive::Session.from_service_account_key('path\to\cliet_secret.json')
#
#  spreadsheet = session.file_by_id(file_id)
#  export_filename = "AC_Order_#{Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}.#{export_format.split('/').last}"
#  export_path = File.join(export_directory, export_filename)
#
#  spreadsheet.export_as_file(export_format, export_path)
#
#    puts "File exported to: #{export_path}"
#end

#file_id = 'randomnumbersandletters'
#export_format = 'pdf'
#export_directory = '\path\to\export'

#export_google_sheet(file_id, export_format, export_directory)

end
```

I've tried adding format_data.to_s at the end of the "format_data_plain_text" method to ensure the data is converted to a string. I've also tried adding "temp_file_content = File.read(temp_file_path)" but it must be something else because the same error was returned regardless of these additions.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the full error message, including the stack trace? The error message usually tests you exactly in which line the error occurred. It would be great if you could test is what line in your code raised the error.

Comment: Try to reduce your code to the relevant section where the error occurs. Most likely, you don't need 100+ lines to reproduce the error.

Comment: Sure thing- I've added the full error for better clarity. Also Stefan, if I knew what part of the code was causing the issue I would definitely do that. The issue is I can create a program that sends an email with the SKU and QTY as text, and I can create a program that adds the SKU and QTY to a google sheet, but when I try to combine the two together and add the sheet as an attachment instead of as text to the email, this is when I encounter the error described above. I am not sure where exactly in the code the issue is happening as I can get the isolated programs to run successfully.

Comment: @ZachS is it this line `session = GoogleDrive::Session.from_service_account_key("client_secret.json", timeout_sec: 300)
` the error message shows *"from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/google_drive-3.0.7/lib/google_drive/session.rb:85:in `from_service_account_key'
  from ex5.rb:38:in \`insert_data'"* everything else posted is reasonably irrelevant

Comment: It seems that when I comment out add_file(temp_file_content) from the email content section, the program runs in the sense that the data is inputted into the google sheet, and the email sends with the text I specified in the body. There must be an issue related to the temp_file_content portions of the code where the program is unable to add the sheet file to the email as an attachment. I've noticed I can even add the line "add_file(file_path)" and the email sends successfully with my local spreadsheet. Can this be more easily resolved by adding the data to a local spreadsheet?

Comment: Regarding the error message: the value for `"scope"` in your `client_secret.json` file apparently is a hash, but it has to be an array or a string.

Comment: @engineersmnky, in the example I provided I am using add_file(file_path) and I had initially commented out the code relating to temp_file_content. The issue seems to be taking place somewhere in the process of saving the sheet as a temp file and attaching that temp file to the email. If the issue is related to the insert_data method, then why is it successfully inserting the data into the google sheet file without issue? It seems to extract the requested data and format it accordingly. I really apologize for the confusion.

Comment: the json file that I am using was provided by google's developer console and I have not made any edits to that file.

Comment: @ZachS does the file contain a `"scope"`?

Comment: @spickermann I've updated the error messages accordingly.

Comment: @stefan the file does not contain the word scope whatsoever.

Comment: I think `timeout_sec: 300` is parsed as the scope argument, try `GoogleDrive::Session.from_service_account_key("client_secret.json", GoogleDrive::Session::DEFAULT_SCOPE, timeout_sec: 300)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`GoogleDrive::Session.from_service_account_key`](https://github.com/gimite/google-drive-ruby/blob/v3.0.7/lib/google_drive/session.rb#L80-L94) has the following method signature:

```
def self.from_service_account_key(
    json_key_path_or_io, scope = DEFAULT_SCOPE, client_options = nil,
    request_options = nil
)
```

The 4 positional arguments are:

- `json_key_path_or_io` (required)
- `scope` (optional, defaults to [`DEFAULT_SCOPE`](https://github.com/gimite/google-drive-ruby/blob/v3.0.7/lib/google_drive/session.rb#L32-L35))
- `client_options` (optional)
- `request_options` (optional)

If you call:

```
GoogleDrive::Session.from_service_account_key("client_secret.json", timeout_sec: 300)
```

then `timeout_sec: 300` is treated as a hash for the `scope` argument, hence the type error.

In order to provide a 3rd argument, you have to pass the 2nd argument, too:

```
GoogleDrive::Session.from_service_account_key(
  "client_secret.json",
  GoogleDrive::Session::DEFAULT_SCOPE,
  timeout_sec: 300
)
```

This is a shortcoming of positional arguments. It would be easier if they had used keyword arguments.

Comment: The [docs](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/google_drive/GoogleDrive%2FSession.from_service_account_key) do actually identify this "As with from_config, you can configure Google API client behavior with client_options and request_options. **Unlike in from_config, these are passed as positional arguments.**" That being said it does not appear `timeout_sec` is a valid option any way [Source](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-ruby-client/blob/main/google-apis-core/lib/google/apis/options.rb#L18)